# Chamar um método em outra classe Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, classes, método

Bom dia senhores, estou com uma dúvida, estou tentando chamar um método que está em outra classe porém não está funcionando, esse mesmo método já funciona se usar outro layout, só queria implementa-lo na activity_main, poderiam me ajudar ?

Código da Classe Parametro que está funcionando:

```
public class Parametro extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    DadosOpenHelper db = new DadosOpenHelper(this);
    public EditText selecinfo;
    public EditText selecinfo2;
    public Button btncontador;
    public Button btncontador2;
    public Button btncontador3;
    public Button btnemail;
    public Button btnemitente;
    public Button btnemitente2;
    public Button btnemitente3;
    public Button btnimpressora;
    public Button btnimpressora2;
    public Button btnimpressora3;
    public Button btnrzaosocial;
    public Button btnnomefantasia;
    public Button btnie;
    public Button btncnpj;
    public Button gravar;
    public Button gravar2;

    public String tabela;
    public String descricao;
    public String retorno;


    public int valida = 1;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        selecinfo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.info);
        selecinfo2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.info2);
        btncontador = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncontador);
        btncontador2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncontador2);
        btncontador3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncontador3);
        btnemail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonemail);
        btnemitente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonemitente);
        btnemitente2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonemitente2);
        btnemitente3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonemitente3);
        btnimpressora = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonimpressora);
        btnimpressora2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonimpressora2);
        btnimpressora3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonimpressora3);
        btnrzaosocial = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonrazaosocial);
        btnnomefantasia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnomefantasia);
        btnie = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonie);
        btncnpj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncnpj);
        gravar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttongravar1);
        gravar2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttongravar2);

        btnnomefantasia.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnrzaosocial.setOnClickListener(this);
        btncnpj.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnie.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnemail.setOnClickListener(this);
        gravar2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnnomefantasia:
                descricao = "nomefantasia" ;
                tabela = "emitente";
                retorno = "";
                String nomefantasia = "nomefantasia" ;
                SQLiteDatabase d1 = db.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor1 = d1.query(tabela , new String[]{descricao, nomefantasia},null, null, null   ,null,null,null);
                if (cursor1.moveToFirst()){

                    do{

                        retorno = cursor1.getString(0);
                        selecinfo2.setText(retorno);
                    }while (cursor1.moveToNext());
                }
                if(valida == 1){
                    gravar2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            modelEmitente emit = new modelEmitente();
                            emit.setNomefantasia(selecinfo2.getText().toString());
                            db.addnomefantasia(emit);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gravado Nome Fantasia", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btnrazaosocial:
                descricao = "razaosocial" ;
                tabela = "emitente";
                retorno = "";
                String razaosocial = "razaosocial" ;
                SQLiteDatabase d2 = db.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor2 = d2.query(tabela , new String[]{descricao, razaosocial},null, null, null   ,null,null,null);
                if (cursor2.moveToFirst()){

                    do{

                        retorno = cursor2.getString(0);
                        selecinfo2.setText(retorno);
                    }while (cursor2.moveToNext());
                }
                if(valida == 1){
                    gravar2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            modelEmitente emit = new modelEmitente();
                            emit.setRazaosocial(selecinfo2.getText().toString());
                            db.addrazao(emit);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gravado Razao Social", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btncnpj:
                descricao = "cnpj" ;
                tabela = "emitente";
                retorno = "";
                String cnpj = "cnpj" ;
                SQLiteDatabase d3 = db.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor3 = d3.query(tabela , new String[]{descricao, cnpj},null, null, null   ,null,null,null);
                if (cursor3.moveToFirst()){

                    do{

                        retorno = cursor3.getString(0);
                        selecinfo2.setText(retorno);
                    }while (cursor3.moveToNext());
                }
                if(valida == 1){
                    gravar2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            modelEmitente emit = new modelEmitente();
                            emit.setCnpj(selecinfo2.getText().toString());
                            db.addcnpj(emit);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gravado CNPJ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btnie:
                descricao = "ie" ;
                tabela = "emitente";
                retorno = "";
                String ie = "ie" ;
                SQLiteDatabase d4 = db.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor4 = d4.query(tabela , new String[]{descricao, ie},null, null, null   ,null,null,null);
                if (cursor4.moveToFirst()){

                    do{

                        retorno = cursor4.getString(0);
                        selecinfo2.setText(retorno);
                    }while (cursor4.moveToNext());
                }
                if(valida == 1){
                    gravar2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            modelEmitente emit = new modelEmitente();
                            emit.setIe(selecinfo2.getText().toString());
                            db.addie(emit);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gravado IE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btnemail:
                descricao = "emailcontador" ;
                tabela = "emitente";
                retorno = "";
                String emailcontador = "emailcontador" ;
                SQLiteDatabase d5 = db.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor5 = d5.query(tabela , new String[]{descricao, emailcontador},null, null, null   ,null,null,null);
                if (cursor5.moveToFirst()){

                    do{

                        retorno = cursor5.getString(0);
                        selecinfo2.setText(retorno);
                    }while (cursor5.moveToNext());
                }
                if(valida == 1){
                    gravar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            modelEmitente emit = new modelEmitente();
                            emit.setEmailcontador(selecinfo.getText().toString());
                            db.addemail(emit);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gravado Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Código aonde estou tentando puxar na MainActivity :

```
public void incluiparam(View view) {

       Parametro parameto = new Parametro();
       parameto.onClick(view);


    }
```

Lembrando que estou tentando puxar o "onClick", eu não sei se é possível, se alguém puder me ajudar eu fico agradecido.

Comment: e se você colocar o método como estatic? ```static```

Comment: Testei com static também porém não funcionou

Comment: Você ta tentando usar uma função de uma activity em outro activity é isso ? você pode falar mais do problema talvez possamos te passar outra solução .

Comment: Isso mesmo, a função onClick está na activity Parametro e estou tentando usar ela na MaiActivity

Comment: é só chamar a função implicitamente : `new Parametro().onClick()` (não esqueça de colocar o método como static)